# Use of toward or to in a sentence

Tags: prepositions

I wrote one sentence

People having contributed to the society are always remembered

Because the ultimate destination of their contribution is the society so we know the destination.

But my teacher said that it should be towards instead of to.

But I am not understanding why should I use towards here?

Comment: When you say "the society", do you mean a specific one, like "The Society For the Beautification of Main Street", or *society* in a general sense like the society they live in?  Because *society* as a general phenomenon doesn't take an article.

Answer (score 1):

Oh prepositions!  As a general rule on this one, people contribute "to" things.

> She contributed [her time] to the cause [Alzheimer research].
>
> He contributed [his money] to his church.

In AmE using "toward" in the above examples would sound stuffy, awkward, and out of place.  However, the organizations in the above examples work toward their goals.

> The Alzheimer research foundation works toward a world free of the disease.
>
> His church works toward world peace.